# Is it possible to find all articles of a given category which have quality issue templates?

Tags: wikipedia

For example, I would like to find all articles in [`[[Kategorie:Maschinelles_Lernen]]`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie:Maschinelles_Lernen) which have issues. One issue are missing sources. Articles with this kind of issue are in [`Kategorie:Wikipedia:Belege fehlen`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie:Wikipedia:Belege_fehlen).

There is at least one in both ([Global Network of Dreams](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Network_of_Dreams)), however, when I use [catscan2](https://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php) it seems not to find it.

How can I get a list of all Wikpedia articles within `[[Kategorie:Maschinelles_Lernen]]` which have obvious issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the parameter `incategory` in the searchbox you can do it, but you have to do it for each combination of the issues you are looking for. This will be solving your example:

https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=incategory%3A%22Maschinelles+Lernen%22+incategory%3A%22Wikipedia%3ABelege+fehlen%22&title=Spezial%3ASuche&go=G%C3%A5+till

What I actually typed in the search box was:

```
incategory:"Maschinelles Lernen" incategory:"Wikipedia:Belege fehlen"
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to get all articles with quality problems?

Comment: Not in one single search. You would have to do it for each category of the quality problems you are interested in.